# Search Github Repositories with filename inputs.conf

Tags: python, api, github

I am writing python code, to query Github API, to get all the repo names.

Search Criteria:

1. Repo names starting with `"wf-d"`
2. Repo must also contain file named `inputs.conf`

```
url = github_Base_URL + "/api/v3/search/repositories?q=wf-d+in:path"
response = requests.get(url, headers=header, verify=False)
```

The above code, gives me all the repos, with `wf-d` in the reponame.
I need to filter further, to get repo names, if repo contains filename called `inputs.conf`

I tried

```
q=wf-d+in:path+filename:inputs.conf
```

in the above URL, but it does not work.

Comment: you could add link to documentation. maybe it doesn't have function to search `filename`, or maybe it has to search it in every repo separatelly.

Comment: I search in Google and I don't see `filename:` in any documentation or tutorial.